# How can we send an email from Databricks to some recipient(s), using Gmail, and add some attachments?

Tags: email, gmail, databricks

I am using Databricks and I am trying to figure out how to send an email to some recipients (probably several receivers) using Gmail. I Googled this before posting here. I found some sample code, as shown below. The code runs and it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't actually do anything at all. This is what I have now.

```
# Email parameters
sender_email = "fname_lname@gmail.com" 
receiver_email = "fname_lname@gmail.com"
password = "pswd"

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders

# Attachment parameters
# attachment_path = "/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/your_account/Daily_Vehicles_Test.csv" 

# Create a multipart message and set headers
message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email
message["Subject"] = "CSV Attachment Test"
# Customize the body message
body = 'Hello, please find the daily view of the vehicles in the attachment.'

# convert the body to a MIME compatible string
body = MIMEText(body) 
# attach it to your main message
message.attach(body) 

# Open the attachment file in bynary
# with open(attachment_path, "rb") as attachment:
#     # Add file as application/octet-stream
#     part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
#     part.set_payload((attachment).read())

# Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email    
#encoders.encode_base64(part)

# # Add header with pdf name
# part.add_header(
#     "Content-Disposition",
#     f"attachment; filename={attachment_path}",
# )

# # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
# message.attach(part)
# text = message.as_string()
```

This is Python and it's supposed to run in a Databricks environment. Some lines of code are commented out, as you can see. Basically, I'm really trying to do a few things here.

1. Use Gmail/SMTP.
2. Send email to multiple recipients.
3. Attach some objects, such as:

   a dataframe

   an image

   a CSV file